# Jenkins trigger build on specific commit message of branch

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I did a little search and googling for this issue, but most of the posts are related on how to isolate (by using git plugin etc.)

What I'm wondering is there a way to configure a jenkins job to trigger a build on specific commit message (let's say if it contains "build") on the branch I specified.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Commit Message Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Commit+Message+Trigger+Plugin) to achieve this.

Once you install this plugin, go to your job configuration page and under `Build Environment` section check `Enable Commit Message Trigger`,then add the keyword that will cause the job to trigger.

[image]

Comment: does this plugin checking the commit message in branchwise or in all of the commits?

Comment: It depends upon the branch you are building in your job. So, yeah it can check commit message branch-wise. But, if you are not specifying any particular branch in your job, then it will check for all the commits.

Comment: there's not enough documentation for the plugin, and the version number (0.1) seems unreliable.
I've tried giving keyword as "[ci BUILD]" and push a commit that contains this keyword, but build doesn't start

Comment: Can you show me your configuration and your commit message?

Comment: it's okay I've arranged it, the keyword should be the "BUILD" or else, and the commit message should have [ci BUILD] in it

Comment: it didn't work for me. any other setting i should know to make this working sir?
i used local repo, should i push to remote after commit?

Comment: this plugin has been depricated... see: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2021/12/22/deprecated-ruby-runtime/

Answer (score 0):

The answers by @ANIL is totally correct just a few improvement to make thinks clear.

[image]

> if you put the keyword as **admin** as shown in image then in your commit message you must
> have **"ci admin"** included and it works. It didn't work without adding ci ahead of keywords in my commit message for me.

**We don't have to add ci in keywords in the build environment setting.**