# How to skip Jenkins job triggered by gerrit patchset based on commit msg

Tags: regex, jenkins, triggers, jobs, gerrit

Is it possible to skip jenkins job if there is a specific word in the COMMIT_MSG?
I have configured my gerrit waiting for the following things (see below) and I would like to skip the flow in case I push something like "jenkinsLocal" in the commit msg.

git commit -m "jenkinslocal so skip this build"
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

[image]

Comment: This question was already answered at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942569/jenkins-trigger-build-on-specific-commit-message-of-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942569/jenkins-trigger-build-on-specific-commit-message-of-branch)

Answer (score 0):

When the job is triggered by the patchset creation, you can start by checking the $GERRIT_CHANGE_SUBJECT variable and, if is the case, stop the process.